# Letting third-party JavaScript access global variables

Tags: javascript, api, security

I'm creating an API for non-programmers to write third-party code for a virtual multiplayer battlebot arena. The syntax for using globals would be nice:

```
function Step() {
    if (sensor.wall) {
        movement.brake();
        movement.turnLeft();
    }
    if (sensor.enemy) {
        movement.shoot()
    }
    if (movement.speed < 1)  {
        movement.accelerate(.1);
    }
}
```

Globals in the above example would be `sensor` and `movement`. The script writer doesn't care where they come from, just that they're accessible. (No, this isn't the final syntax. Just prototyping here.)

Scripts would be run on both the client (a browser) and server (via Node or Spidermonkey).

So, how to do this? It seems like my options are:

- Set all the globals lexically then `eval()` the script (but that's bad, right?)
- Set all globals in the global scope and then run the script normally (but what about DOM globals, like `window`?)

I could probably secure the global scope using [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/). I'd also like this to be performant since lots of `Step()` functions will be run per second on the same server.

Comment: It's not at all clear in your example what's supposed to be "global" and what's not.  It's also not clear what context this code is to run in - server? client? both?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user scripts are received as text and I don't care about bolting down access to `document`, `window`, etc., (it's a private application), `eval()`ing is the best option.

```
function evaluateScript(movement, sensor, content) {
    return eval(content);
}
```